# What does the expression "ranging from something to something" mean?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, phrase-meaning

I am studying for a TOEFL exam and I have a question about this particular exercise. The exercise is about a short text which talks about what is aggression and the theories that study it. Edit: Here are paragraphs one and two of the text for more context:

> Aggressive behavior is any behavior that is inteded to cause injury, pain, suffering, damage, or destruction. While aggressive behavior is often thought of as purely physical, verbal attaks such as screaming and shouting or belittling and humiliating comments aimed at causing harm and suffering can also be a type of aggression. What is key to the definition of aggression is that whenever harm is inflicted, be it physical or verbal, it is intentional.
>   Questions about the causes of aggression have long been of concern to both social and biological scientists. **Theories about the causes of aggression cover a broad spectrum, ranging from those with biological or instinctive emphases to those that portray aggression as a learned behavior.**

I transcribed the exercise I need help with below:

> Which of the sentences below expresses the essential information in the highlighted sentence in paragraph 2? *Incorrect* choices change the meaning in important ways or leave out essential information.

The highlighted sentence the exercise refers to is the following one (which is also bold on the larger passage above):

> Theories about the causes of aggression cover a broad spectrum, ranging from those with biological or instinctive emphases to those that portray aggression as a learned behavior.

According to the answer key, the correct answer is this:

> B) Theories that consider aggression biological are more accepted than those that consider it learned.

However, I chose the following answer:

> C) Various theories about aggression attribute it to either natural or learned causes.

I didn't understand why the correct answer is B. That's why I am asking about the meaning of "ranging from something 1 to something 2". As far as I know, this expression only states that something 1 and something 2 are elements inside a particular set. Does this expression convey the idea that the first element mentioned is more important than the second element mentioned?

Thanks!

Comment: You are correct. The answer key is just plain wrong. The original says nothing about what is accepted or not.

Comment: @Jim thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Yes, I agree with Jim, B is wrong. As a native BrE speaker, C is the meaning I take from the original sentence.

Comment: "Ranging from A to B" only says that the theories lie somewhere in between A and B, where A and B are the extremes, limits or opposites. It says nothing about their rank, acceptance, validity or plausibility.